# Why PCL's download version is 1.5.1 but its doc is 1.6.0?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is [PCL download page](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/).

Here is [PCL doc page](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__features.html).

Where is PCL 1.6.0 to download?

What's happened that PCL's download version is 1.5.1 but its doc is 1.6.0?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37606/why-pcl%27s-download-version-is-1.5.1-but-its-doc-is-1.6.0?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't really an answers.ros.org question, but that's because those are the in-development documents, which apply to the next version of PCL, which is going to be 1.6.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3